# Tricky Edge Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

i am learning opencv for a project and i need to detect edges on a very bad image. I want to mark the edge between the light gray and the dark gray area.(marked yellow) My problem is to find the right combination of operators to do this job.

So far i tried simple thresholding, but the gray-value on the right circle goes from 30 to 100 which is found everywhere else in the image. The image is also very noisy and filters (median,gaussian) are not very useful. I am also familiar with Sobel-Edge Detection but the wanted egde is not big enough to sort out the edges that are made from the noise.

I also tried the Canny-Operator but even this operator detects many edges on the right side of the image because of the many white and black pixels.

Someone an idea?

[image: Marked][image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried using histogram equalization? I doubt this'll do wonders, but try applying ```cv.equalizeHist()```, maybe you'll get better edges then...

Comment: a big median blur can remove those small speckles

Comment: i tried equalizehist() , but it makes it even worse. Light areas are brighter than before

Comment: @Micka i use median bluring but when it is to big, i will lose the edges

Comment: size 51 looked ok to me. Another approach could be kmeans color quantization with 2-4 colors (after median blur).

Comment: @Micka Ok, in never thougt such a big mediaBlur() could help, but its better than before. The edge is now bigger than the other and the edge-image shows my wanted edge the most. I dont know if its possible to perfectly highlight this edge without any other small edges.

Comment: How do i use kmeans color segmentation?

Comment: @EdwinB.: color segmentation is for color images !